# Why is bind(this) necessary in this line?

Tags: javascript

I am following google chrome's extension development guide here:
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html

In line 41 of this file: http://sprunge.us/NFjZ

```
requestKittens: function() {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("GET", this.searchOnFlickr_, true);
  req.onload = this.showPhotos_.bind(this);
  req.send(null);
},
```

, they used the bind function like this
this.showPhotos_.bind(this); and without this binding, the example extension will not work. I tested in the showPhotos_ method and verified that "this" is just the kittenGenerator object. Since showPhotos_ is just a method of that object, this should be implicitly done, so why is this binding necessary anyway?

---

Note that google's example will not work due to a spelling mistake in the popup.js file. 
To correct it, change "kittensOnFlickr_" into "searchOnFlickr_".

Comment: Perhaps the method is moved elsewhere later?

Comment: @JanDvorak No, not really.

Comment: Because it's an event handler, and without this binding, you'd lose the scope in your handler. And `this` would call `window`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the binding `showPhotos_` when called from req.onload, the `this` will be `req` not `kittenGenerator`.

Comment: How can I prove this? Thanks!

Comment: Without the binding the alert in `showPhotos_` would show `[object XMLHttpRequest]`

Comment: @CravingSpirit you get an error for e.target.responseXML but the alerts do show http://jsfiddle.net/7DH9r/

Comment: Wow, thanks. It didn't show up in google chrome itself though. Another question: how is the XMLHttpRequest object passed to showPhotos_?

Comment: @CravingSpirit http://jsfiddle.net/7DH9r/1/ e.target is correct, it was throwing the error because you was calling `this.showPhotos_()`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! `req.onload = this.showPhotos_(this)` passes the XMLhttpRequest to `showPhotos_` and at the same time set the context to the object `kittenGenerator`, right?

Comment: @CravingSpirit `req.onload = this.showPhotos_.bind(this)` set the context to the object kittenGenerator. When XMLHttpRequest calls onload it passes the event argument which contains the `XMLHttpRequest` object(e.target).